# Issues with jquery fading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm quite new to jquery and am attempting to fade in/out pages of a gallery when clicking page numbers. The page numbers should also fade to different colours, and a border should fade in/out.

I'm having 2 problems with this. The fade in/out of the images works when on localhost and jsfiddle, but when live there's an issue when first changing the gallery page. Instead of the new page fading in, it appears as if there is no animation at all. After the first click it works fine. This can be seen here (as i mentioned, this doesn't happen in jsfiddle): https://intellidesign.000webhostapp.com/gallery.html

The code is here, but i've also pasted the jquery below: https://jsfiddle.net/adamjroberts91/xpvt214o/524699/

I'm also having some problems with the border around the page numbers. As each number is clicked in the gallery it's supposed to remove a class from the current number and add it to the one that's been clicked but this doesn't seem to happen. The only time any classes are changed is when clicking back to page 1 - where the class is removed from the number 1 but not re-added.

Code (Page 3 may look like it isn't loading but its currently the same images as page 2):

```
// Add the class names for each gallery to variables
const pageOne = '.gallery__page-1';
const pageTwo = '.gallery__page-2';
const pageThree = '.gallery__page-2';

//Add the class names for pagination numbers to variables
const pageNumberOne = '.gallery__pagination-number-1';
const pageNumberTwo = '.gallery__pagination-number-2';
const pageNumberThree    = '.gallery__pagination-number-3';

//Set the selected page and pagination to page 1
let currentPage = pageOne;
let currentPageNumber = pageNumberOne;

//Fade out the current page and fade in the new one
//Change color/outline of pagination numbers to show page selected
$(document).ready(() => {
    $(pageTwo).hide();
    $(pageThree).hide();
    $(pageNumberOne).click(() => {
        $(currentPage).fadeOut('slow', () => {
            $(pageOne).fadeIn('slow');
        });
        currentPage = pageOne;
        setTimeout(() => {
            $(pageNumberOne).addClass('gallery__pagination-number-selected');
            $(currentPageNumber).removeClass('gallery__pagination-number-selected');
        }, 500);
        currentPageNumber = pageNumberOne;
    });
    $(pageNumberTwo).click(() => {
        $(currentPage).fadeOut('slow', () => {
            $(pageTwo).fadeIn('slow');
        });
        currentPage = pageTwo;
        setTimeout(() => {
            $(pageNumberTwo).addClass('gallery__pagination-number-selected');
            $(currentPageNumber).removeClass('gallery__pagination-number-selected');
        }, 500);
        currentPageNumber = pageNumberTwo;
    });
    $(pageNumberThree).click(() => {
        $(currentPage).fadeOut('slow', () => {
            $(pageThree).fadeIn('slow');
        });
        currentPage = pageThree;
        setTimeout(() => {
            $(pageNumberThree).addClass('gallery__pagination-number-selected');
            $(currentPageNumber).removeClass('gallery__pagination-number-selected');
        }, 500);
        currentPageNumber = pageNumberThree;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there is a wall of answer here but there are a lot of issues so I'm going to step through some here and I can update my answer as needed.

There is no need to repeat your styles in css. The point of classes is that you can use the same class on multiple elements. Just use a class like .gallery-page instead of duplicating the style rules for .gallery__page-1, .gallery__page-, etc.

The images are too large. Some of your images are over 20mb; it took 52 seconds to load all 140mb that this one page is serving. You can reduce the image size/quality settings and still deliver a good looking set of images.

There is no need to store the jQuery selector string and then repeatedly call the jQuery function to access that item.

```
//bad
var thing = '.thing';
// later on calling this repeatedly
$(thing).addClass(...

// better
var thing = $( '.thing' );
// later on calling this repeatedly
thing.addClass(...
```

Your button classes don't work because the timeout doesn't use the context when the timeout was scheduled, it uses the context at the time the function is called. The context refers to the state of the values of the variables. Specifically in your js currentPageNumber is set to the class that the timeout function will be selecting to add the `selected` class to and remove it from. If that variable was updated within the timeout function it would work more like you expect, but id just use a css transition with delay instead of the js timeout for this.

You don't need to store the current page in a variable in the javascript. Just attach a class like .current or .active to the active element in the dom. When you react to the click, you can fadeout all of the pages, parse the id of the clicked link to get the page number, and fade in the new current one. This will fix your js bug and make your code reusable when adding more pages.

I think the fade in isn't working because jQuery doesn't know the size of the element it is fading in until it has been rendered. You can try adding a height to the pages and see if that fixes the fadein issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far - I'm only a couple days into building this so haven't got round to bits such as reducing image size (makes no difference on local).

You don't need to store the current page in a variable in the javascript > So give all 3 page numbers the same class but different IDs, then parse the id and use to style?

I think the fade in isn't working because jQuery doesn't know the size of the element it is fading in until it has been rendered > I thought by using pageTwo.hide() after (document).ready would mean the elements are rendered before being hidden? Is this wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure about that loading thing but you can test it by setting an image  height